# Given two sets of xyz coordinates and a value for sag (a) can I draw a catenary between those points in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d, curve

I am trying to create a non-moving wire in 3d space in C++ OpenGL using a catenary formula.  I would like to specify the xyz coordinates of the two fixed points (poles the wire is strung between) and a value for a in the formula to represent the amount of sag the wire has. I'll need to loop through the formula based on a precision count (number of line segments to draw).

In my OpenGL world, x and y are horizontal, and positive y is up, so the wire will always sag in negative y. So if you look straight down along the y axis the wire will appear as a straight line.  But the two end points may not be on the same plane horizontally (different y values).

All the examples of a catenary I've seen are 2d...I need to draw it in 3d, which is racking my brain. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd want to do is take a 2D catenary and transform it onto the plane you want.  The implementation you described says it "will appear as a straight line" from above.  So, this equation fits on a 2-dimentional plane that can be translated along the X & Z axes, and rotated around the Y axis to fit a given orientation.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'd have to figure out how to make the two end points match the original given xyz coordinates. How do I determine how much to rotate it.

Comment: You need a rotation matrix about the _y_-axis. You can construct it by the _x_ and _z_ coordinates of the second point relative to the first point with [this](https://i.imgur.com/7eT1OYQ.png) matrix.